# How can I access a list inside of a dictionary in Anible?

Tags: ansible

I have the following dictionary with a list inside (**items**)

```
{
"json": {
    "data": {
        "devices": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "configurationStatus": "SYNCED",
                    "conflictDetectionState": "IN_SYNC",
                    "connectivityState": "ONLINE",
                    "deviceType": "ASA",
                    "highAvailability": "OFF",
                    "interfaces": null,
                    "specificDevice": {
                        "namespace": "asa",
                        "type": "configs",
                        "uid": "12313131231",
                        "vpnId": null
                    },
                    "uid": "1231312313"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "count": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have registered this output under a variable called output. If I go line by line until **items** I can access them with no problem

```
    - debug:
        var: output.json
```

ok!

```
    - debug:
        var: output.json.data
```

ok!

```
    - debug:
        var: output.json.data.devices
```

ok!

```
    - debug:
        var: output.json.data.devices.items

ok: [localhost] => {
    "output.json.data.devices.items": "<built-in method items of dict object at 0x7f88386c8c00>"
```

When I come to items and want to access configurationStatus or deviceType I get the error above. I suspect its due to the items list. Any idea how could I access and register those vars?

Comment: The JSON syntax is correct due to the length of it I just copy pasted the middle section where I'm having the issue not paying attention to the arrays.

Comment: I just fixed the format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `items` is the name of a method on the dictionary class, and when using `.` notation (`foo.bar.baz`), attributes get resolved before keys. So you can't access a key named `items` using this syntax.

Instead, try this:

```
    - debug:
        var: output.json.data.devices['items']
```

That syntax will prefer keys.